# The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/SiteLayout.cshtml": "Scripts"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple view:

```
@model BootstrapTest4.Models.Account.CambioDeClave

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/SiteLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@Model.Title</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pass1)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pass1)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pass1)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pass2)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pass2)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pass2)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Cambiar Clave" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

@section Scripts {
    @System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

this view was made via the **Mvc4** scaffolding system (edit template) and since I use some dataannotations in my model it uses the Scripts Bundle.

the error I am getting is the following:
The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/SiteLayout.cshtml": "Scripts"

searching I found that most people solve the problem adding this to their layout:

```
    @if (IsSectionDefined("Scripts"))
{
    RenderSection("Scripts",false);
}
```

I added that block just before the  tag of my layout but i still get the same error.

as requested: my whole Layout:

```
@model BootstrapTest4.Models.IMenu
@using BootstrapTest4.Utils.Helpers
@using BootstrapTest4.Utils
@{
    Layout = null;
}

    <!DOCTYPE html>


    @{
        Model.usr = (UsuarioWebCliente)Session["DatosUsr"];
        Model.usrDrogSelec = Html.DrogSeleccionada(Model.usr);
        var Lista = Html.GeneraComboDrogs2(Model.usr, Model.usrDrogSelec.cod_drogueria);
    }
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    </head>
    <body style="height: 100%;  ">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div>
                <div id="whitebar">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align: right">
                                @Model.usr.DatUsrs.desc_usuario - @Model.usr.DatUsrs.codigo_ident - @Html.ActionLink("Cerrar Sesion","Logout","Account")
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="bluebar">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.usr.DatUsrs.cod_drogueria, new SelectList(Lista, "Value", "Text"), new { @id = "DDLMENU", data_url = Url.Action("CambiarDrog", "Menu") })
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                Monto Consumido:
                                <label id="SALDO">
                                    @(Model.usrDrogSelec.saldo_actual == 0 ? "0.00" : Convert.ToDecimal(Model.usrDrogSelec.saldo_actual).ToString("#,##.00"))
                                </label>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                Hora Corte: XXXXX
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                Día Corte:
                                <label id="DIA">
                                    @Model.usrDrogSelec.dia_corte
                                </label>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                            <img style="max-height: 20px;" src="~/Content/Images/1381797224_home.png" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            @foreach (var item in Model.MenuCollection)
                            {
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">@item.Name <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                    @if (item.Children.Count > 0)
                                    {
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            @foreach (var childItem in item.Children)
                                            {
                                                <li>@Html.ActionLink(childItem.Name, childItem.Action, childItem.Controller)</li>
                                            }
                                        </ul>
                                    }
                                </li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span><b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Droguería Principal","PrioridadDrogueria","ReportesPrioridadDrogueria")</li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Mensajería</a> </li>
                                    <li> @Html.ActionLink("Cambio de Clave", "CambiarClave", "Account")</li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Actualizar Datos</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                </nav>
                <div id="Content" style="height: 100%; ">
                    @RenderBody()
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="push"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 footer">Test</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @if (IsSectionDefined("Scripts"))
    {
        RenderSection("Scripts",false);
    }
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Did layouts in those examples inherit from some other layouts?

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları the layout does not inherit from  any other layouts. it has the following: Layout = null;

Comment: Show your layout view, looks like you are requiring the Script Section, not making it optional.

Comment: Also, checking if the section is defined is unnecessary. By passing `false` in the second parameter to `RenderSection`, you're already saying the section is optional.

Comment: @Fals I have included the layout file as requested.

Comment: @ChrisPratt whenever it is defined it should be necessary. I included the second parameter (false), to see if it would aid in solving the problem.

Comment: You misunderstand. Of course, if you specify the section, it should be rendered to the page, but all your need is `RenderSection("Scripts", false)`. That will render the section if it is defined and not fail if it isn't. My point is that what you need is the `false` parameter, *not* the `if` block.

Comment: @ChrisPratt ah, got it, Thanks, you are correct in that the if is redundant. I will be sure to remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try only

```
RenderSection("Scripts",false);
```

Instead of

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("Scripts"))
{
    RenderSection("Scripts",false);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should just call `RenderSection`.

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", false)
```

Comment: According to this, IsSectionDefined does have meaning in layout, and is intended to for use in layouts, not views: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2010/12/08/optional-razor-sections-with-default-content.aspx

Comment: `IsSectionDefined` clearly HAS meaning in layout, and returns true if the section is defined in the page being rendered in the layout or not: http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.IsSectionDefined);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true

Answer (score 0):

I got the following error while running the application I resolved it by adding @RenderSection(“Scripts”,required:false) in the _Layout page.

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```